# Who is $default on reduce action in file output autogenerated by bison

Tags: bison, lex, context-free-grammar, bisonc++

Someone knows the sentence:

```
$default  reduce using rule 1 (P)
```

who is $default...
It should be a specific terminal , but which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default action applies to every terminal not specified with another action.

Comment: and so... i want to compile a table look a like the table in dragon book, where i have to put reduce action ? who is the state number and who is the correspondent token ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @FrancescoLanza  Make the table. Fill in the actions for all the specified terminals. Then fill in the empty boxes with the default actions.

Comment: **thank you =D** sure.. I have understood what do you means only now ;) @rici